# Multiplify a number

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source

## Challenge description

*Multiplification* (totally not a made-up word) is a process in which you take two positive integers: `a` and `b`, and produce another integer which is equal to `a` repeated ("glued together") `b` times. For example, multiplifying `3` by `7` gives `3333333`. Similarly, `103` multiplified by `5` is `103103103103103`.

In this challenge, given two positive integers `a` and `b`, output `a` multiplified by `b`. The catch is, you can't use string operations to generate the number - it has to be done in a purely mathematical way. You may only use operators for addition (`+`), subtraction (`-`), multiplication (`*`), integer division (`/`, `//`, `div`), modulo operation (`%`, `mod`) and binary operations (`&`, `^`, `|`, `<<`, `>>` etc.). It's not possible to do in every language, since it has to support arbitrary precision integers.

## Sample inputs / outputs

```
10, 4   | 10101010
3, 9    | 333333333
3737, 2 | 37373737
993, 1  | 993
8888, 8 | 88888888888888888888888888888888
```

Comment: Can I convert to digit list, then concatenate, then convert back to number?

Comment: Yes, but you can't directly concatenate digits, like `[3, 2] -> 32` unless you do it mathematically, that is for example `3*10 + 2`. The point is not to use string operations.

Comment: Is [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89326/48934) your ideal solution?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't use string operations and is therefore valid. Doing something like `f=lambda a,b:int(str(a)*b)` would be cheating.

Comment: Can I compute the length of the number as a string?

Comment: No, that counts as a string operation.

Comment: I wanted to do this [in V](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w4DDpHc&input=Mw&args=Nw) but the string restriction makes it impossible. :(

Comment: If I want to use a language that doesn't have arbitrary precision integers, am I still allowed a non-competing solution that works for the first four test cases?

Comment: Can I print `a` as many times as `b`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Sounds like a string operation to me.

Comment: @Neil Totally, it's still better than nothing. Support for arbitrary precision integers is not a strict requirement, but it won't work for many simple cases, like `102` and `4` (assuming 32-bit integers), that's why I put it there.

Comment: @LeakyNun: No, you may not. The number needs to be produced at some point which is the purpose of the challenge.

Comment: "[...] Support for arbitrary precision integers is not a strict requirement [...]" vs "[...] it has to support arbitrary precision integers [...]" What should we do now?

Comment: @Frozn: Submit your solution and add `only works within <range>`. It's not a complete solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: This falls into one of the classic traps of [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/194): it's written assuming that all languages are C-like and so prohibits other languages unnecessarily. E.g. CJam is banned because it would require a duplication operator to have one copy of `a` to count its length and another to multiply by the corresponding g.p.

Comment: This challenge seems to have a number of contradictions between the body and the comments. Consensus is that any changes made in the comments should be [edited into the body of the challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8112/20283). Until that happens it is unclear which rules apply.

Comment: Unfortunately, although the intentions of this challenge are good, I'd like to point out that in general "Do X without Y" challenges are hard to get right. Golfing often invites one to find loopholes in the rules, but in this case the line between what is and what isn't allowed can get a bit fuzzy.

Comment: It's still unclear if things like for loops are allowed - they aren't one of the mathematical operators. If they can't it's just a competition with who can find the shortest language that can express this formula

Comment: `it has to be done in a purely mathematical way` says it all, doesn´t it? You have to compute the result using only basic numkerical operations. Loops are no loophole imo (as long as you don´t use them to simply print `a` `b` times). btw: what is `//`?

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, 48 bytes

```python
c,n=input();a=1
while n/a:a*=10
print a**c/~-a*n
```

Arithmetic!

Take number `n` and repetition count `c`. First, computes `a=10**num_digits(n)` as the smallest power of 10 above `a`. Then, the floor division `a**c/(a-1)` gives a number of the form `1001001001001` with `c` ones, spaced apart by the digit-length of `n`. Multiplying by `n` then replaces each `1` with `n`, giving `c` concatenated copies of `n`.

A same-length recursive version:

```python
f=lambda c,n,a=10:a**c/~-a*n*(a>n)or f(c,n,a*10)
```

This one has to start at `a=10` because `a=1` causes a division-by-zero error.

Comment: Nice, pretty much the same what I came up with, except I wasn't sure how to go about golfing `log10(a)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
jL,?h:.cL
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=akwsP2g6LmNM&input=WzEwOjRd&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

The `j` operator concatenates the first thing in an array to itself as many times as the second thing in the array.

In other words, `[10:2]` would produce `101010`.

This operator uses integer in the implementation so is completely usable.

However, it is one concatenation too many.

Therefore, we use the ability of Brachylog to prove things to deal with this:

```
jL,?h:.cL
jL          input after being treated by the j operator yields L
  ,         and
   ?h:.cL   first element of input concatenated with output is L
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8 lambda, 268 characters

Arbitrary precision ruins everything, here are the BigIntegers:

```
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;import java.math.BigInteger;(a,b)->{BigInteger r=ZERO;int d=(int)(Math.log(2)/Math.log(10)*a.bitLength()+1);if(TEN.pow(d-1).compareTo(a)>0)d--;while((b=b.subtract(ONE)).compareTo(ZERO)>=0)r=r.multiply(TEN.pow(d)).add(a);return r;}
```

And here the ungolfed version:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import static java.math.BigInteger.*;

public class Q89322 {

    static BigInteger expand(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
        BigInteger result = ZERO;

        int digitCount = (int) (Math.log(2) / Math.log(10) * a.bitLength() + 1);
        if (TEN.pow(digitCount - 1).compareTo(a) > 0) {
            digitCount--;
        }
        while ((b = b.subtract(ONE)).compareTo(ZERO) >= 0) {
            result = result.multiply(TEN.pow(digitCount)).add(a);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope that logarithm is also counted as a valid mathematical operation :)

Getting the digits of the BigIntegers powered by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23773083/3764634). With only `int` or `long` this could be way shorter :/

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>105</s> <s>139</s> <s>136</s> 134 bytes

```
function m($a,$b){$s=$x=$a;for($f=10;$x>9;$x=bcdiv($x,10))$f=bcmul($f,10);for(;$b=bcsub($b,1);)$s=bcadd($s,$a=bcmul($a,$f));return$s;}
```

arbitrary precision needs some room in PHP, but I´ll look if I can shrink this a bit.

Comment: I'm quite sure `log10` doesn't have arbitrary precision.

Comment: @LeakyNun: log10 does not, true. But `a=1e+xx` is sufficient to get an exact length of `a` unless `xx` is greater than `INT_MAX`. I assume that `a` does not have that many digits, so I spare the code to implement `bclog10` or add a `bcmul` or `bcdiv` loop.

Comment: oh ... no `log`, no `pow` allowed ... back to the editor.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 38 bytes

```haskell
n%c|a<-until(>n)(*10)1=n*div(a^c)(a-1)
```

Everyone forgets about `until`!

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,n,p=1:p<=x and f(x,n,p*10)or n and f(x,n-1,p)*p+x or 0
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/7xCwpd)

First recursion to find the power, second recursion to complete the "concatenation".

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
i*jQTET
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=i%2ajQTET&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A4%0A3%0A9%0A3737%0A2%0A993%0A1%0A8888%0A8&debug=0&input_size=2)

Convert to digit list, repeat for that many times, then convert to number.

```
i*jQTET  Q: first input, E: second input
  jQT    convert Q to base T (10) as a digit list
 *   E   repeat for E many times
i     T  convert from digit list to number
```

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE Salt-votes lol

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES7), 43 bytes

```
f=(a,b,c=1)=>c>a?(c**b-1)/~-c*a:f(a,b,c*10)
```

Works up to `f(9000,4)`. (Looks like I rediscovered @xnor's formula.) 56-byte ES6 version or 52-byte ES6 version with an even smaller range:

```
f=(a,b,c=0,d=0)=>c<a?f(a,b,c*10+9,d*(b='1e'+b)+--b):d/c*a
f=(a,b,c=1,d=1)=>c>a?~-d/~-c*a:f(a,b,c*10,d*='1e'+b)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DẋḌ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ROG6i-G4jA&input=&args=MTA+NA)

```
DẋḌ  Main chain, argument: x,y
D    Convert x to list of digits
 ẋ   repeat y times
  Ḍ  Convert back to number
```

Answer (score -1):

### Common Lisp, 73 bytes

```
(lambda(a b)(loop for x below b sum(*(expt 10(*(ceiling(log a 10))x))a)))
```

Answer (score -1):

## k, 20 bytes

Same idea as **Pyth** solution.

Only supports up to 64 bit signed int range.

```
{10/:(y*#d)#d:10\:x}
```

Example

```
k){10/:(y*#d)#d:10\:x}[103;2]
103103
```